# Standard deviation of travel times

Tags: probability, standard-deviation

Suppose that travel times for Swinburne students are normally distributed with mean of $32.5$ minutes and a standard deviation of $5$ minutes.

Complete the following sentence, giving figures correct to $1$ decimal place.

$95$% of travel times would fall between **_______**  minutes and **____** minutes.

Comment: Please include your own efforts.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $P(-z \leq Z \leq z)=2\Phi(z)-1$, with $z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$